# Code for sending order confirmation and its working

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, order-confirmation

I have a data ware house running in PostgreSQL server ,i'm loading data using PYTHON to the DWH from Magento, I want to consolidate all the mailing process from my DWH , for which i have devised a mailing mechanism using python.

Now my issue is how to get the order confirmation details from Magento to my DWH as I need to send an order confirmation email to users as soon as they places an order(Time period is not an issue).

So i need to understand how the mail sending mechanism in Magento is working in case of Order confirmation? Is there a trigger for that or an event? **Does anyone have the SQL code for checking this?**

Any ideas/suggestions will be heartily welcomed.

Using Version Magento 1.9

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Comment: i'm using Magento version 1.9

Answer (score 0):

I may need some (or a lot) of clarification to give a proper answer, but the event that triggers an order confirmation email is in `[magento-root]/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` the function named `sendNewOrderEmail()`, which then calls `queueNewOrderEmail` in the same class to do the heavy lifting.

Depending on the information that you are trying to capture, you'll probably want to look at `$paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())`

..or you could do `Mage::log(array_keys($this->getData()));` which would give you the data assigned to the order that you are working with.  Then, you'd use `$this->getData('the-key-you-found')` to pull the specific information.

If you are trying to do something in sql, the data from this message and information is store in the `core_email_queue` and `core_email_queue_recipients` tables.  It is not there long in most cases, and when the email cron is run, sending the email, the entry is removed.  [More information on that can be found here](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/cron.html)